# Where does a Ubuntu system store the username and password for a mounted system?

Tags: 12.04, mount, smb

I have mounted a windows system from a folder.

First I pressed `ctrl` + `l`. Then on top in location by **SMB** protocol I connected to the remote system. I provide the remote system username and password for the first time. Also marked to save the password.

So, for the next time I only provide the SMB url and it connects to the remote system. I found inside my home folder, there is an hidden folder `.gvfs` got created. Inside that folder I found the mounted remote system.

Even I restart the machine, it doesn't ask for the username and password again. Ubuntu must store the username and password of the remote system. **Where does it store these?**

Comment: look inside `/etc/fstab` do you see a line similar to `SMB_CREDENTIALS=`?

Comment: No. I didn't find anything like `SMB_CREDENTIALS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK your solution is :

In Dash type : **Passwords and keys**

[image]

In Password Tab :

[image]

If You delete it, the password will be deleted and will ask you for new credentials for your share .

Try it and reply .

Comment: Thanks a lot! You showed me a very important area of Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is stored in `/etc/samba/smbpasswd`

If you want to remove the stored password from samba share ,

you can use:

`sudo smbpasswd -x username`